# How to call async method from PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, inotifypropertychanged

I have an WPF application based on MVVM architecture. I am implementing the common and widely used `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on my ViewModels, because I need to react on user interaction.

But how do I perform an asynchronous action (e.g. loading some data) from within the synchronous PropertyChanged event handler **without** using `async void` 'hacks'?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The main reason why i need to avoid `async void` is because I am working in an test driven environment. Async void methods are not testable :(

Comment: Using `async void` with event handler is not a hack. It is the prefered solution. Event handlers by nature are fire and forget, so it shouldn't be expected for event handler to return any value.

Comment: Loading data in a property is generally considered bad practice anyway. That is typically one of the criteria for creating a method as opposed to using a property.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is not about `async void`.

Usually you want to fire async operation and let your property setter return.
Sample snippet:

```
private string carManufacturerFilter;

public string СarManufacturerFilter
{
    get { return carManufacturerFilter; }
    set
    {
        if (carManufacturerFilter != value)
        {
            carManufacturerFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            // fire async operation and forget about it here;
            // you don't need it to complete right now;
            var _ = RefreshCarsListAsync();
        }
    }
}

private async Task RefreshCarsListAsync()
{
    // call some data service
    var cars = await someDataService.GetCarsAsync(carManufacturerFilter)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // ...
}
```

Note, that there are a lot of things to add here:

- since this is fire-and-forget approach, you need to block user input until operation is running. In other words, there should be some sort of busy indicator;
- you may want to delay async operation firing. This is usually applicable, when there are string properties. You don't want to fire async operation after each char typed by user. Instead it's desirable to wait user to complete input;
- there could be several properties, which fire the same async operation (imagine complex data filter). Some of them should fire operation immediately (e.g. checkbox), some of them need delay before firing;
- you need to handle exceptions inside async method and display errors somehow.

P.S. I strongly recommend you to take a look at [Reactive UI](https://reactiveui.net/).

Comment: Won't it complain about not awaiting awaitable method?

Comment: If you're about compiler warning, then assignment (`var _ = `) suppresses it. IRL this code will be wrapped into something like `AsyncCommand` etc. This is a sample, which intended to give OP basic idea. This is not production-ready code.

Comment: How can someone achieve unit testing with this code?

Comment: @Dennis How should I assert anything when the task cannot be awaited when using `async void`?

Comment: There's no async void here. Here is regular async method, that returns Task. But anyway you must not await it, because this will make UI freeze.

Comment: IMHO, this is a code smell for 2 reasons. 
1) You're not awaiting the task 
2) You are  "artificially" surprising the compiler warning about not awaiting the task by assigning the task to empty variable.

Comment: @MichalCicatka, why do you think that *every* task must be awaited? :) There are a lot of cases, when one wants to fire-and-forget tasks. This is one of them - I just want to start async operation. I'm not interested in its result immediately.

Comment: @Dennis Because when the task would fail, the exception  won't get thrown. Thus this pattern creates undefined behavior. IMHO there's a reason why the compiler warns you about not awaiting tasks. When you don't care about the result immediately, save the task in a variable a await it later.   

And it should have been "suppressing"  in the last message of course :)

Comment: @MichalCicatka, this works different way. Normally F-&-F scenario assumes `try`-`catch` inside task method, so in case of exception one can handle it. There's no any obligation to await task. I have no idea, where you read this. Compiler warns you, yes, but if you *really don't want to* await task (and this is one of such cases), it's ok to tell the compiler "I know what happens here, it's not a mistake".

Comment: Having the try-catch block inside the RefreshCarsListAsync() method is probably a solution if You don't want to throw an exception in it. I agree that this solution is valid and more or less save, I'd still rather subscribe the PropertyChanged event and call the method in the event handler. Feels to me like a cleaner solution and you are also able to throw an exception in the RefreshCarsListAsync() method.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `async void` is supported is to allow using `await` in event handlers, which are usually void.
If you want it to be testable, write the entire code in another `async Task` method and have the event handler call it directly. Test this method in your tests.

```
void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChangedAsync(e)
}

// Test this method
async Task OnPropertyChangedAsync(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but I'd say this. First, notice that `INotifyPropertyChanged` says that your view model will implement

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
```

Secondly, if you inspect `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, you'll see that it's a `delegate`, of course:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
```

So why not implement your own delegate using `Func<>`? For example, if you're looking to stick with the `(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs  e)` parameter pattern that `PropertyChanged` uses, then I would implement something like

```
public Func<object?, PropertyChangedEventArgs, Task>? PropertyChangedAsync { get; set; }
```

in the same place (or in place of) `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;`.

From there you can "wire it up" just as you would `PropertyChanged`:

```
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;    
ViewModel.PropertyChangedAsync += OnViewModelPropertyChangedAsync;

private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something (synchronously) with the notification
}

private Task OnViewModelPropertyChangedAsync(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something (asynchronously) with the notification
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

By the way, if you really want to get fancy, you could also create a custom `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event with an interface very similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Obviously, the only difference is you'd want to return `Task` or `Task<T>` instead of void. The solution that I mentioned above using `Func<object?, PropertyChangedEventArgs, Task>` is just a lot more concise (one line).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't support async calls.  You need to do a hack, or rethink you strategy.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is not intended for async actions.  Its goal is to enable a class notify the UI that its data has changed.  The UI works in a dedicated thread, so cross-thread operations must be avoided.

You should use the "dreaded" `async void` approach.

You can also use `Dispatcher.BeingInvoke (async () => { … await …} )`, but it will be the same as using `async void`.